# Updated my model but the views didn't update. Did I do something wrong, or do I need to do that myself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm new to rails so apologies if I don't make myself clear.
I have set up my databases/models (same thing yes?). Later realised I missed a column on my database so added it with rails g migration etc. Then did rails db:migrate and added it to the schema. That all worked perfectly.

My problem comes with my views. There is a form connected to that database to fill out when uploading a picture. The form is ticking some boxes of that column and adding some text. The new columns did not get added to the form - do I need to do that manually? I can, that's no problem, just wondering if I did something wrong.

Thanks

This is the part of the schema I'm particularly talking about

```
 create_table "paintings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean "trees"
    t.boolean "river"
    t.boolean "cabin"
    t.boolean "waterfall"
    t.boolean "guest"
    t.boolean "animalguest"
    t.string "startcolour"
    t.string "shape"
    t.integer "likes"
    t.bigint "profile_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "beach"
    t.text "other"
    t.index ["profile_id"], name: "index_paintings_on_profile_id"
  end
```

"Beach" and "Other" are the new columns. They seem to have added just fine.

```
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :trees %>
    <%= form.check_box :trees %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :cabin %>
    <%= form.check_box :cabin %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :river %>
    <%= form.check_box :river %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :waterfall %>
    <%= form.check_box :waterfall %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :guest %>
    <%= form.check_box :guest %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :animalguest %>
    <%= form.check_box :animalguest %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :startcolour %>
    <%= select_tag(:startcolour, options_for_select([['white', 1], ['black', 2], ['clear', 3], ['acrylic black', 4], ['grey', 5], ['mixed', 6], ['other', 7]], 1)) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :shape %>
    <%= form.text_field :shape %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :likes %>
    <%= form.number_field :likes %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :picture %>
    <%= form.file_field :picture %>
  </div>
<%#
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :profile_id %>
  <%#  <%= form.text_field :profile_id %>
 <%# </div> %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and there is the bulk of the form. You'll see the beach and other didn't get added. The form was originally created through scaffold. The other two columns were just added now using migration

Comment: could you show the code for this so that it will be easy to debug.

Comment: My schema model im talking about:

 ``` create_table "paintings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean "trees"
    t.boolean "river"
    t.boolean "cabin"
    t.boolean "waterfall"
    t.boolean "guest"
    t.boolean "animalguest"
    t.string "startcolour"
    t.string "shape"
    t.integer "likes"
    t.bigint "profile_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "beach"
    t.text "other"
    t.index ["profile_id"], name: "index_paintings_on_profile_id"
  end``` 

Those last two columns added did not change my form

Comment: could you show the view and  controller

Comment: sorry limited chars is making this difficult. There is a little more of this but this is essentially it
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :trees %>
    <%= form.check_box :trees %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :cabin %>
    <%= form.check_box :cabin %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :river %>
    <%= form.check_box :river %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :waterfall %>
    <%= form.check_box :waterfall %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :guest %>
    <%= form.check_box :guest %>
  </div>

Comment: yo can edit the original post and add there

Answer (score 3):

The views do not auto-update if you change the database schema, you must do so yourself. Same for any business logic in the controller, if any.

I'm guessing you've used the scaffold feature to create the above then went in and changed the schema. You want to go in and edit the view and add:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :beach %>
    <%= form.check_box :beach %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :other %>
    <%= form.text_field :other%>
  </div>
```

This will render the form controls you require, as per your schema changes.

If you are looking for an easier way to build such interfaces without having to handle such situations then you probably want to look at the Rails admin gem: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin - it helps you set up CRUD interfaces real fast, including search features, sorting, pagination and so on. Downside is you have to spend some time in the front-end learning how to use it, and you will likely have to ditch it later if you want some more complex business logic in your application - its easier than diving into its code to figure out where to plug in your custom code. Unless you learn how to use a builder or operations pattern where you can easily delegate without having to do much work with Rails Admin itself.

Comment: Ah awesome that's all I needed to know! And yer I know how to do it by hand, and I got some of the frontend stuff down too. Just new to the whole rails thing and all this magic is doing my head in!
Cheers :)

Comment: Welcome to Wonderland then, enjoy :)